# Detect a click on an animated button

Tags: android

i'm making a program on android : the user has to push on an animated button to make the button invisible and increase score. But, while testing, the animated button is disabled during animation : the animation is perfectly done but we can't use animated button during animation. I've searched answers but i haven't found.

**MainActivity :**

```
Public int score = 0;
Public Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Public Animation anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.translate_up);
button1.startAnimation(anim1);

button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

           score++;
           button1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    }});
```

**Translate_up, XML animation :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shareInterpolator="false">

<translate
   android:duration="1000"
   android:fromXDelta="0"
   android:fromYDelta="0"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
   android:startOffset="0"
   android:toXDelta="0"
   android:toYDelta="-900"
/>
```

Sorry for my bad English, i hope you understand me.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button itself is actually working on it's original position. So although it looks like your button is sliding to the top, you can still click on the empty space in it's original position and trigger the onClick event.

I am afraid an animation won't work here. If it is a game then you should create a gameloop and update the position of your views (e.g. your button) in the gameloop method.

Comment: Exact, i didn't know gameloop, that's perfect for me, thanks man !